# How can I verify a signed message(not transaction) from a dApp (elrond)?

Tags: python, multiversx, erdpy

I am trying to create backend authorization for the maiar wallet user on the backend. I am creating server-side authentication using python, but am unable to figure out to verify signed messages on the server. I am looking for something similar to the web3 signing messages and verifying them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I also have a similar issue, trying to generate the signature with Erdjs and failing...
Looked at the Metabonding SC example and did like there, but not sure how to actually generate the signature. Also looked over the Mandos tests there but no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at these code snippets for frontend and Nestjs code, it might help you:

https://gist.github.com/michavie/40d0cc0564e7819a94ee503836a25525
https://gist.github.com/raress96/4135c92049667e9df0d88d4b3b65bb7c